# CSV File To DB In Yii

Tags: php, yii

Am working with yii and anyone can help me to upload CSV file with multiple rows to Database using yii.

Table structure

CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`phase` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

And my test CSV file contain following fields

| title | Description | Phase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Login | Login & logout | 4 |

My View page form.php

```
<div class="form">
<?php 
 $form = $this->beginWidget('LiveActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'project-document-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
            ));
    ?>   

     <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <?php echo $form->fileFieldRow($model,'filename');?>
         <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('error')): ?>
            <div class="success" style="color:red;" id="error_file">
                    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
            </div> 
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')): ?>

            <div id="success" class="success" style="color:green;">
                    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?> 
        <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('myHideEffect', ' $( "#ProjectDocument_filename" ).parent().append($( "#error_file" ));', CClientScript::POS_READY ); ?>   
             <div class="form-group">
                 <?php

                $this->widget('LiveButton', array(
                    'buttonType'=>'submit',
                    'type' => 'primary',
                    'label' => 'Upload File',
                    'size' => 'small',
                    'icon'=>'icon-upload icon-white',
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'uploadCSV','style'=>'float:left;'),
                ));
                ?> 
         </div>
    </div>
  
         <div class="form-actions">
            <?php echo CHtml::link('<i class="icon-download-alt icon-white"></i>Download CSV Format',array('ProjectDocument/downloadfile'),array('class'=>'btn btn-success','style'=>'float:right;')); ?>
         </div>
    
    </div>
    
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>   
    
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){$("#success").fadeOut(10000);});
        </script>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Csv file uploading is working proprly, but I have no idea how to insert the data from the file and store into the DB.

Comment: May you show your controller consumes csv file code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using MySQL or MariaDB. If you have the file locally on the server (i.e. uploaded correctly), you can execute SQL

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/file' INTO TABLE users;
```

See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html) for details.

Direct SQL in Yii2 is done using:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand(sql, params)->execute();
```

Then it could look like

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \':file\' INTO TABLE users', [':file' => path])->execute();
```